# How to create an anchor and redirect to this specific anchor in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, anchor, page-jump

I'm trying to create unique anchors for every comment on my blog so a person can take the url of an anchor and paste it in their browser, which will automatically load the page and scroll down to the point in the page where their comment starts.

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way but I've tried this which was to no avail.

Comment view - Fail 1 - when pasted in a browser this link does not scroll down to the desired position

```
<%= link_to '#', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => comment.post, :anchor => 'comment_' << comment.id.to_s %>
```

Comments controller - Fail 2 - Correct url in browser but no scrolling happens it just stays at the top of the page

```
redirect_to :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => @post, :anchor => 'comment_' + @comment.id.to_s
```

If someone could help I'd be very grateful :)

UPDATE: The solutions below almost work, however I come out with the following URL which isn't being scrolled to if I click on it.

# 
i.e. http://localhost:3000/posts/please-work

Comment: In order to do the screen scroll the url has to specify where you want it to scroll to. To do this you have to have a #comment_123 at the end of your url. Where the text after the '#' needs to match the value of a 'name' attribute in a anchor tag. The url in your update won't scroll for lack of a #.

Comment: Yeah I tried that - it didn't work!

Turns out the :anchor creates this url

<a anchor="comment_126" href="/posts/please-work">#</a>

But using :name changes it to this, which as you say is what I'm after. Any idea why this is the case?

<a name="comment_126" href="/posts/please-work">#</a>

Comment: Oh, ok I see. Sorry for the confusion. I updated my answer but it looks like you have to manually concatenate the anchor onto the end of the url. Otherwise the link_to tag thinks that :anchor is a html attribute. Hope this works :)

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for helping me get there :)

Comment: You can add anchor like this: post_path(@post, :anchor => "some_text"). Just pass anchor as a parameter to post_path, not to link_to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the `link_to` code that you have in your question. Then in your list of comments you have to make sure that you have an anchor tag named the same thing in the link.

So this:

```
 <%= link_to 'Your comment', post_path(@comment.post) + "#comment_#{@comment.id.to_s}" %>
```

will generate something like this

```
 <a href="localhost:3000/posts/2#1comment_234">Your comment</a>

 /* html code */     

 <a name="comment_1234">This is a comment</a>
```

You have to manually tack on the `#comment_` otherwise the link_to method thinks that the :anchor attribute that you are passing it is for that  tag.

Comment: You should use the answer by XGamerX. This would work but it isn't very elegant.

Answer (score 82):

Actually, anchor is an option for the path, not for the link_to

```
<%= link_to '#', post_path(comment.post, :anchor => "comment_#{comment.id}") %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001565

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall")
       # => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an improvement on @XGamerX's answer.

```
<%= link_to '#', [comment.post, { anchor: dom_id(comment) }] %>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to '#', post_path(comment.post, anchor: dom_id(comment)) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to '#', post_path(comment.post), :anchor => "comment_#{comment.id}" %>
```

Comment: This almost works, however I come out with the following URL which isn't being scrolled to if I click on it.

<a anchor="comment_111" href="/posts/please-work">#</a>

i.e. http://localhost:3000/posts/please-work

Answer (score 0):

this is best way:

```
<%= link_to '#', post_path(comment.post, anchor: dom_id(comment.id)) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

These links will scroll down to position where you have code like:

```
<a name="comment_1"></a>
```

I don't know if there are helpers that will do it for you, but it is very simple and you can write your own.