# Rails : Linking an anchor from a different controller/view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, link-to

```
<%= link_to (:controller => "company_stuff", :action => "index", :anchor => :menu), :class => 'links' do %>
    <li>Terms of Use</li>
<% end %>
```

I am having difficulty linking a page which is on a different controller and also the link is an anchor. Basically the `controller` is called `company_stuff` the `action` is `index` and the `anchor` is called `#terms`

Comment: In this particular case, the anchor should be passed as a parameter to the action?

Comment: still doesn't work. There must be a syntax/formatting error somewhere

Comment: You didn't answer if the anchor value is a parameter.

Comment: The anchor is a normal anchor link.. eg `www.example.com/#terms`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `:controller` `:action` `:anchor` was not being passed through as a hash, separate from the CSS `class`

Below is the solution

```
<%= link_to "Terms Of Use", {:controller => "company_stuff", :anchor => "terms"}, :class => "links" %>
```

Comment: Great! accept your own answer so people can use it later when reading your question.

Comment: I have to wait for two days :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try something like this

```
<%= link_to index_company_stuff_path + "#terms", :class => 'links' do %>
    <li>Terms of Use</li>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to index_company_stuffs_path + "#terms", :class => 'links' do %>
    <li>Terms of Use</li>
<% end %>
```

Depending on your controller name and route.

You can find more information on this question [How to create an anchor and redirect to this specific anchor in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757891/how-to-create-an-anchor-and-redirect-to-this-specific-anchor-in-ruby-on-rails)